# using RViZ in Docker

Tags: rviz, docker, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everybody,

i would like to use Rviz in a Docker Container with ROS-Kinetic, which is using also on the host system. The host-system has this software and hardware implemented:

- Ubuntu 16.04
- ROS-Kinetic
- Nvidia GTX 1060 and the driver 384.130
- installed nvidia-docker2

The idea is to create a docker-container from the current software version, to update the whole system later. So i found this Introduction on [ROS Wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/docker/Tutorials/Hardware%20Acceleration), which I need to visualize the container. So i tried the nvidia-docker2 part, but it doesnt worked. I running the container with the following arguments:

```
docker run –name doc_geste –gpus all –network host –env=DISPLAY -env=NVIDIA-VISIBLE_DEVICES=all -env=NVIDIA_DRIVER_CAPABILITIES=all –env=QT_X11_NO_MITSHM=1 -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix:rw –runtime=nvidia –privileged -it docker_geste
```

Before i started the docker container i enter the following line in the terminal: **xhost +local:docker**

The error which i get is:

```
libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
Could not initialize OpenGL for RasterGLSurface, reverting to RasterSurface.
```

My Dockerfile (i edit some of this line):

```
FROM stereolabs/zed:2.2-devel-cuda9.0-ubuntu16.04

# Possible to use "Source" 

RUN rm /bin/sh && ln -s /bin/bash /bin/sh
   
# nvidia-container-runtime
ENV NVIDIA_VISIBLE_DEVICES \
    ${NVIDIA_VISIBLE_DEVICES:-all}
ENV NVIDIA_DRIVER_CAPABILITIES \
    ${NVIDIA_DRIVER_CAPABILITIES:+$NVIDIA_DRIVER_CAPABILITIES,}graphics

# Setup ROS
RUN apt-get update -y && \
    DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y tzdata && \
    sh -c 'echo "deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list' && \
    apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-key C1CF6E31E6BADE8868B172B4F42ED6FBAB17C654 && \
    apt-get update -y && \
    DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -y --no-install-recommends install ros-kinetic-desktop-full ros-kinetic-openni2-* python-rosinstall python-rosdep python-rosinstall-generator python-wstool build-essential nano python-catkin-tools git openssh-server nano net-tools iputils-ping python-numpy python-scipy python-matplotlib ipython ipython-notebook python-pandas python-sympy python-nose  ros-kinetic-rosbridge-server ros-kinetic-twist-mux ros-kinetic-cob-scan-unifier ros-kinetic-joy software-properties-common ros-kinetic-ddynamic-reconfigure-python x11-xserver-utils mesa-utils libgl1-mesa-glx\
    cmake usbutils git -y --allow-unauthenticated && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN add-apt-repository ppa:gijzelaar/snap7; \
    apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends libsnap7-dev libsnap71; \
    mkdir -p /root/.ssh/ #&& chmod 700 /root/.ssh

SOME GITLAB STAFF

RUN rosdep init && \
    rosdep update --rosdistro kinetic && \
    cd /home/ && mkdir -p robot/fifi_geste_ws/src/

WORKDIR /home/robot/

COPY SOME DATA to Docker

RUN tar -xzvf cudnn-9.0-linux-x64-v7.tgz; \
     cp cuda/include/cudnn*.h /usr/local/cuda/include; \
     cp -P cuda/lib64/libcudnn* /usr/local/cuda/lib64; \ 
    chmod a+r /usr/local/cuda/include/cudnn*.h /usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcudnn*; \
    rm cudnn-9.0-linux-x64-v7.tgz; \
    rm -r cuda

RUN cd fifi_geste_ws/src; \
    #Get the ROS-Package in my Workspace
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* && cd .. && \
    catkin_make -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda/lib64/stubs -DCUDA_CUDART_LIBRARY=/usr/local/cuda/lib64/stubs -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="-Wl,--allow-shlib-undefined"; \
    rm /root/.ssh/id_ed25519

COPY /Docker_Geste/SN16233.conf /usr/local/zed/settings/
```

My SH-FIle

```
# If not working, first do: sudo rm -rf /tmp/.docker.xauth
# It still not working, try running the script as root.

XAUTH=/tmp/.docker.xauth

echo "Preparing Xauthority data..."
xauth_list=$(xauth nlist :0 | tail -n 1 | sed -e 's/^..../ffff/')
if [ ! -f $XAUTH ]; then
    if [ ! -z "$xauth_list" ]; then
        echo $xauth_list | xauth -f $XAUTH nmerge -
    else
        touch $XAUTH
    fi
    chmod a+r $XAUTH
fi

echo "Done."
echo ""
echo "Verifying file contents:"
file $XAUTH
echo "--> It should say \"X11 Xauthority data\"."
echo ""
echo "Permissions:"
ls -FAlh $XAUTH
echo ""
echo "Running docker..."

docker run -it \
    --env="DISPLAY=$DISPLAY" \
    --env="QT_X11_NO_MITSHM=1" \
    --volume="/tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix:rw" \
    --env="XAUTHORITY=$XAUTH" \
    --volume="$XAUTH:$XAUTH" \
    --net=host \
    --privileged \
    --runtime=nvidia \
    docker_geste:latest \
    bash

echo "Done."
```

I tried so much to visualize Rviz in a docker, but it doesnt working. It is possible at all to run RViZ in a docker on ROS-Kinetic? If it yes, than how?

Regards,
Markus

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/391195/using-rviz-in-docker/) by [MarJooBa](https://answers.ros.org/users/89863/marjooba/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2021-11-18

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) on 2021-11-18**:
Please take a look at this prior answer: https://answers.ros.org/question/300113/docker-how-to-use-rviz-and-gazebo-from-a-container/

It’s for ROS Melodic but I believe you can use it for Kinetic as well. There is confirmation as recent as of June 2021

**Comment by [MarJooBa](https://answers.ros.org/users/89863/marjooba/) on 2021-11-19**:
so i tried this, but it didnt worked. I get the same error again.

I add with my my docker_file and the SH-File on the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My solution is to use [this image](https://hub.docker.com/r/nvidia/cudagl/) to get it with cuda and opengl. Then installing ros, some tools and the dependencies. Then I create the docker with the following parameters:

```
docker run –name ContainerName –gpus all –network host –env=DISPLAY –env=NVIDIA_DRIVER_CAPABILITIES=all -env=NVIDIA-VISIBLE_DEVICES=all –env=QT_X11_NO_MITSHM=1 -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix:rw –runtime=nvidia –privileged -it DockerImage
```

And it worked!

---

Originally posted by [MarJooBa](https://answers.ros.org/users/89863/marjooba/) with karma: 11 on 2021-11-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0